# reimplement the shouldInterruptJavaScript() in Qt (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, webkit

According to the help of Qt for QWebPage [Slot **ShoudInteruptJavaScript**], located [here:](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#shouldInterruptJavaScript)

> This function is called when a JavaScript program is running for a long period of time.
>
> If the user wanted to stop the JavaScript the implementation should return true; otherwise false.
>
> The default implementation executes the query using QMessageBox::information with QMessageBox::Yes and QMessageBox::No buttons.
>   
>   **Warning: Because of binary compatibility constraints, this function is not virtual. If you want to provide your own implementation in a QWebPage subclass, reimplement the shouldInterruptJavaScript() slot in your subclass instead. QtWebKit will dynamically detect the slot and call it.**

I don't want qt show a message when javascript runnig for long period of time.
So, how can i reimplement ShoudInteruptJavaScript? 
and where should i create it?
Please show me a sample
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

All the info you need is in the documentation.

Create a new custom class that inherits from QWebPage, make sure it's a Q_OBJECT to receive signals.

```
class MyFunkyPage : public QWebPage {
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    bool shouldInterruptJavaScript() {
        QApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 42);
        // Ignore the error
        return false;
    }
};
```

Set the page of your QWebView to a custom subclass of QWebPage.

```
setPage(new MyFunkyPage());
```

Then when your page gets this signal it won't stop the script from executing, and it won't show a dialog.

Comment: why do you add the processEvents call?

Answer (score 1):

The MyFunkyPage solution potentially leaks memory and causes crashes because the object passed to setPage has no parent and setPage does not take ownership. Instead,

```
class QWebPageWithoutJsWarning : public QWebPage {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QWebPageWithoutJsWarning(QObject* parent = 0) : QWebPage(parent) {}
public slots:
    bool shouldInterruptJavaScript() {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Set the page of your QWebView to the custom subclass of QWebPage, parented on the WebView,

```
void suppressJSWarning(QWebView& webView) {
    webView.setPage(new QWebPageWithoutJsWarning(&webView));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@anson-mackeracher almost had it right.

Qt needs it to be a private slot, not a public one.  Here's what works for my class:

```
class MyFunkyPage : public QWebPage {
  Q_OBJECT

private slots:
  bool shouldInterruptJavaScript() {
    // Ignore the error  (return true to kill the runaway JavaScript)
    return false;
  }
};
```

Set the page of your QWebView to a custom subclass of QWebPage.

```
setPage(new MyFunkyPage());
```

I just tested this with Qt 4.8.4 and it works like a charm. I didn't need the processEvents call.