# Overridden slot shouldInterruptJavaScript() not being called

Tags: c++, qt

I want to suppress the Javascript timeout warning in QtWebkit from Qt4.8.6. I created a subclass of QWebPage (shown below) and used setPage to add it to the QWebView. However, the dialog is still appearing. Searching on the internet I have found example that look like my code that people say are working (e.g.[reimplement the shouldInterruptJavaScript() in Qt (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284511/reimplement-the-shouldinterruptjavascript-in-qt-c)). I must be doing something silly. If I override a function like javascriptConsoleMessage *that* gets called OK.

My class:

```
class NoDialogWebPage : public QWebPage
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    NoDialogWebPage(QObject * parent = 0) : QWebPage(parent) {}

public slots:
    bool shouldInterruptJavaScript()
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

How it is called from the QWebView's container:

```
m_pWebView = new QWebView(this);
m_pWebPage = new NoDialogWebPage(m_pWebView);
m_pWebView->setPage(m_pWebPage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt needs it to be a private slot, not a public one.  Just change

```
public slots:
bool shouldInterruptJavaScript()
```

to

```
private slots:
bool shouldInterruptJavaScript()
```

I just tested this with Qt 4.8.4 and it works like a charm.